# Getting phonenumber of sim using phonegap and phonenumber plugin and how to code it?

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Phonegap Desktop App and online Phonegap build service. I am making my first android app using phonegap. I have coded for getting phone number but it doesn't show phone number. I gettin alert "failed" from the function.I have successfully added github plugin. my code is as below.

```
       function get_number()
{
    //this.bindEvents();
    alert("enterd");
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",get_it, false);
    function get_it()
    {
      if (window.plugins && window.plugins.phonenumber)
      {
        window.plugins.phonenumber.get(success, failed);
        function success(phonenumber) {
        console.log("My number is " + phonenumber);
        alert("success");
        alert(phonenumber);
                                    }
        function failed()
        {
          alert("failed");
        }
      }
    else
    {
      alert("plugins are not loaded");
    }
  }


}
```

[this image from phonegap build plugin list the first plugin I am using.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEopv.jpg)

Comment: link to pluig: https://github.com/oneminutedistraction/phonenumber

Comment: Usage given in read me file.

window.plugins.phonenumber.get(success, failed);

function success(phonenumber) {
    console.log("My number is " + phonenumber);
}

Comment: I am running app on lolipop os

Comment: r u testing in real device ??

Comment: @NareshKumar  yes I am using real device